# Find Duplicate with 2 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

My code below find the duplicates based on 2 criteria:

1. The first criteria is the **Name** in `Column A`
2. The second criteria is the **Country** in `Column D`

`Sheet("RawData")` :

[image: CompanyName | Duns ID | Product ID | CountryName]

`Sheets("Conso")` after the macro:

[image: CompanyNames | Duns ID | Product ID]

What I am looking is to **increase the speed** of this code, because I am working with more than 150K rows and it takes hours.

```
Sub MDMDuplicates()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim wsRawData As Worksheet, wsConso As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Lastrow As Long, LastrowConso as Long
Dim SupNameToCheck As String, ConsoSupplierDUNS As String, ConsoSupplierMDM As String, ConsoSupplierNAME As String



Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set wsRawData = WB.Sheets("RawData")
Set wsConso = WB.Sheets("Conso")

Lastrow = wsRawData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With wsRawData

For i = 2 To Lastrow

SupNameToCheck = .Cells(i, "A").Value
SupCountryToCheck = .Cells(i, "D")
ConsoSupplierDUNS = ""
ConsoSupplierMDM = ""
ConsoSupplierNAME = ""


j = Lastrow
    Do
        If i <> j And SupNameToCheck = .Cells(j, "A") And SupCountryToCheck = .Cells(j, "D") Then

            If ConsoSupplierNAME = "" Then

            ConsoSupplierDUNS = .Cells(i, "B") & "," & .Cells(j, "B")
            ConsoSupplierMDM = .Cells(i, "C") & "," & .Cells(j, "C")
            ConsoSupplierNAME = SupNameToCheck & "," & .Cells(j, "A")

            Else

            ConsoSupplierDUNS = .Cells(j, "B") & "," & ConsoSupplierDUNS
            ConsoSupplierMDM = .Cells(j, "C") & "," & ConsoSupplierMDM
            ConsoSupplierNAME = .Cells(j, "A") & "," & ConsoSupplierNAME

            End If

           .Cells(j, "A").EntireRow.Delete

        End If

        j = j - 1

      Loop Until j = 1


LastrowConso = wsConso.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not ConsoSupplierNAME = "" Then
        wsConso.Cells(LastrowConso, "B") = ConsoSupplierDUNS
        wsConso.Cells(LastrowConso, "C") = ConsoSupplierMDM
        wsConso.Cells(LastrowConso, "A") = ConsoSupplierNAME
    Else
        wsConso.Cells(LastrowConso, "B") = .Cells(i, "B")
        wsConso.Cells(LastrowConso, "C") = .Cells(i, "C")
        wsConso.Cells(LastrowConso, "A") = SupNameToCheck
 End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm unclear on why the **name** has to be repeated in the result. It would seem to me that having **AAA** rather than **AAA, AAA** as a result would be more efficient and more functional for later processing (e.g. using a lookup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that there is repeated loops cycling through the entire data matrix trying to identify duplicates. Putting the whole data block into a two-dimensional variant array would help. Faster lookups could be achieved with [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)'s use of the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) but a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object with its unique collection index can greatly reduce the looping and the lookups.

I would heartily recommend either setting the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor ► [Require variable declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835.aspx) or manually putting `Option Explicit`¹ at the top of each module code sheet. Currently, the *SupCountryToCheck* var was left undeclared.

```
Sub MDM_Duplicates_Jeeped()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsRawData As Worksheet, wsConso As Worksheet
    Dim sKey As String, tmp As Variant
    'late binding of the dictionary object
    Dim d As Long, vTMPs As Variant, dMDMs As Object
    'early binding of the dictionary object (see footnote ²)
    'Dim d As Long, vTMPs as variant, dMDMs As new Scripting.Dictionary

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False    'turn off unnecessary environment overhead

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRawData = wb.Worksheets("RawData")
    Set wsConso = wb.Worksheets("Conso")

    'late binding of the dictionary object
    Set dMDMs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dMDMs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With wsRawData
        'dump all of the values into a 2-D variant array
        vTMPs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Value2
        'for testing purposes - first 50 rows
        'vTMPs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(50, 4)).Value2
    End With

    'populate the dictionary with name/country pair keys and
    'comma separated duns/product concatenated item pairs
    For d = LBound(vTMPs, 1) To UBound(vTMPs, 1)
        sKey = Join(Array(vTMPs(d, 1), vTMPs(d, 4)), ChrW(8203))
        If dMDMs.Exists(sKey) Then
            dMDMs.Item(sKey) = Join(Array(Split(dMDMs.Item(sKey), ChrW(8203))(0) & Chr(44) & Format(vTMPs(d, 2), "000000000"), _
                                          Split(dMDMs.Item(sKey), ChrW(8203))(1) & Chr(44) & vTMPs(d, 3)), ChrW(8203))
        Else
            dMDMs.Add Key:=sKey, _
                      Item:=Join(Array(CStr(Format(vTMPs(d, 2), "'000000000")), Chr(39) & CStr(vTMPs(d, 3))), ChrW(8203))
        End If
    Next d

    'put the dictionary's collated keys and items back into a redimmed vTMPs
    'late binding needs to iterate through for each key
    Erase vTMPs
    ReDim vTMPs(1 To dMDMs.Count, 1 To 4)
    d = 1
    For Each tmp In dMDMs.Keys
        vTMPs(d, 1) = Split(tmp, ChrW(8203))(0)
        vTMPs(d, 2) = Split(dMDMs.Item(tmp), ChrW(8203))(0)
        vTMPs(d, 3) = Split(dMDMs.Item(tmp), ChrW(8203))(1)
        vTMPs(d, 4) = Split(tmp, ChrW(8203))(1)
        d = d + 1
    Next tmp

    'dump all of the temp variant array's values back into the results worksheet
    With wsConso
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(vTMPs, 1), UBound(vTMPs, 2)) = vTMPs
    End With

    'restore the environment
    appTGGL

End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

> <sup>150,000 rows of random sample data generated to mimic your own sample data³ (sorted or unsorted).
>        Late Binding: 13.94 seconds
>        Early Binding: **9.48 seconds**</sup>
>   <sub>Sample XLSB workbook available temporarily at: [MDMDuplicates.xlsb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/MDMDuplicates.xlsb)</sub>

[image: mdmduplicates]

I wasn't too sure on how to deal with the DUNS numbers. Typically for DUNS, I use true numbers formatted as `000000000` or `000000000-0000` (the latter for DUNS+4) as numerical lookups are faster and more versatile than text-based lookups. However, for this I used forced text with leading zeroes to make 9 digit placeholders. The **productid** numbers were similarly forced into text with a `'` [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) so you didn't end up with some as text-that-look-like-numbers (multiple) and some as true numbers (single).

I have also retained the country codes and augmented them to the three letter ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 standard. It didn't make sense to have the country codes as one of the unique criteria and then discard them from the results.

---

¹ <sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This 
will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable 
declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is 
widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>

² <sub>If you convert the late binding of the **[Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)** object to early binding, you must add **[Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx)** to the VBE's Tools ► References.</sub>

³  <sub>Tests were performed on a five-year-old business class i5 laptop with 8 Gbs of DRAM and Excel 2010 version 14.0.7166.5000 (32-bit). To my mind, that is the low end of the scale on which an operation like this should be performed.</sub>

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, i am gonna try this tomorrow. However i understood the logic and you are the only one who gave me such good and precious advise for what i was looking for. thanks again i will tell you tomorrow the result! you're awesome!

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do before making any changes to this code, is to improve its *readability*. I saw `.Cells` and thought "oh we're in a With block" ...and then had to look three times to find the `With` statement.

The keyword here, is **indentation**.

```
Sub DoSomething()
....
....With SomeObject
....|...
....|...If SomeCondition Then
....|...|...DoActionOne
....|...Else
....|...|...DoActionTwo
....|...End If
....|...
....|...Do
....|...|...DoActionThree
....|...Loop
....|...
....End With
....
....For i = 1 To 10
....|....
....|....DoActionFour
....|....
....Next
....
End Sub
```

When the `Else` blocks don't line up with the corresponding `If` statement, or when a `Loop` keyword doesn't line up with its corresponding `Do` keyword, or when nested blocks line up in column 1, you basically set yourself up for making a change that introduces a bug.

Proper indentation cannot be underestimated.

---

You have redundant object references:

- If `WB.Sheets("RawData")` has *CodeName* `Sheet1`, name it `RawDataSheet` and use that reference instead.
- If `WB.Sheets("Conso")` has *CodeName* `Sheet2`, name it `ConsoSheet` and use that reference instead.

"CodeName" is a property of all sheet objects in Excel VBA; there's a global object reference pointing to these, readily available for you to use - no need to fetch it from `WB.Sheets` collection, which by the way could give you non-worksheet objects, since the `Sheets` collection includes *Charts*, among other sheet types. You probably meant to use the `WB.Worksheets` collection instead. But then again, you don't need it - just use the global object VBA gives you for free instead.

---

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> ```

Whenever you set that value to `False`, you need to handle runtime errors and make sure that *whatever happens*, the method can't exit without setting it back to `True`. Otherwise Excel will look "frozen" when it's actually completely responsive, just not redrawing itself... because you told it not to.

Don't assume things won't blow up. They always do.

```
Sub DoSomething()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '...

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    'handle errors
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Now that's great, but you're deleting rows, which should trigger a recalculation if calculation is set to `xlAutomatic`. Consider not only turning off `ScreenUpdating`, but also setting `Calculation` to `xlManual` while you're doing your thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw an answer out here as well. First things first, I agree with Mat's Mug about using *codenames*, but I'm going to leave it as is for my answer, out of simplicity. Same goes for indentation and mostly everything else.

Out of personal preference, I don't like variables all defined on the same row - it hinders my ability to go see the variables easily. I also like to define them as soon as I dim them.

I would turn this

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim wsRawData As Worksheet, wsConso As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Lastrow As Long, LastrowConso as Long
Dim SupNameToCheck As String, ConsoSupplierDUNS As String, ConsoSupplierMDM As String, ConsoSupplierNAME As String



Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set wsRawData = WB.Sheets("RawData")
Set wsConso = WB.Sheets("Conso")

Lastrow = wsRawData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Into this:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsRawData As Worksheet
Set wsRawData = WB.Sheets("RawData")
Dim wsConso As Worksheet
Set wsConso = WB.Sheets("Conso")

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = wsRawData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LastrowConso As Long

Dim supNameToCheck As String
Dim consoSupplierDUNS As String
Dim consoSupplierMDM As String
Dim consoSupplierNAME As String
```

Now it's easier to read and you'll notice [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

Speaking of variables names - give them meaning. You've done a good job of this except for `i` and `j`. Now, those are acceptable in most circles, so I can't say it's wrong, but why  not use something like `rowNumber`? And why use `j`? You already have `i` and `lastRow` defined.

Going into your `With` and `Do` loops has me backtracking all over the place trying to figure out what's going on with the `i` and the `j` and the weird spacing. This first `Do Loop` is just for populating your strings, right?

Seems to me that sorting your sheet would reduce your loop, so

```
wsRawData.Columns("A:Z").Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("D:D"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Now we're ordered by column A and D, so we just need to start at the bottom and go up:

```
For rowNumber = lastRow To 2 Step -1
```

Now you check for duplicates based on columns A and D? <s>But your example is just finding A duplicates and combining the other columns, isn't it?</s> An easier way to do that would be like this (unless I'm misunderstanding):

```
  For rowNumber = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(rownumber, a) = Cells(rownumber - 1, a) And Cells(rownumber, 4) = Cells(rownumber - 1, 4) Then
        Cells(lastRow - 1, 2) = Cells(lastRow, 2) & ", " & Cells(lastRow - 1, 2)
        Cells(lastRow - 1, 3) = Cells(lastRow, 3) & ", " & Cells(lastRow - 1, 3)
        Rows(rownumber).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next
```

Loop through the rows only once and if two criteria match, combine the others.
Now you only need 1 loop and you don't need those strings or anything. Cutting a loop out as well as what Mat spoke of will really help your speed.

I also got with of the `With` block - just use your worksheet variables in your ranges.

I can't quite figure out what's happening at the bottom with the other worksheet, so I'm not addressing it. You could probably bring it into your single loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered pushing all this data into an Access database, then using a query to identify the duplicates? That seems to me to be the right tool for this job.